# Convert Image Map Area Coords to Absolutely Positioned Div

Tags: css, html, imagemap, area

I have an image map with areas that I would like to try and automatically convert to an absolutely positioned div.

I want to convert this:

```
<area shape="rect" coords="662,346,937,426" href="#" />
```

to this (which is wrapped in an absolute div):

```
<a style="left:662px; top:346px; width:275px; height:80px;" href="#" />
```

Basically it boils down to converting this:

```
<area shape="rect" coords="A,B,C,D" href="#" />
```

to this (which is wrapped in an absolute div):

```
<a style="left:Apx; top:Bpx; width:C-Apx; height:D-Bpx;" href="#" />
```

I would like to find a way to automate this via a script and/or find/replace. I don't think regular expressions would work because they don't do any calculations (feel free to prove me wrong). It probably could be done with Javascript, but I don't know much :/

Comment: You need an obligatorily use javascript. Add a javascript or jquery tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve this with JQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cords = $('.area1').attr('coords').split(',');
    $('.href1').attr('style', 'left:'+cords[0]+'px; top:'+cords[1]+'px; width:'+ (cords[2]-cords[0]) +'px; height:'+ (cords[3]-cords[1]) +'px')
});​
</script>


<area class='area1' shape="rect" coords="662,346,937,426" href="#" />
<a class='href1' style="left:0; top:0; width:0; height:0;" href="#" ></a>​
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/G8TLm/1/